# How to use percentage padding top and bottom in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to achieve dynamic padding top and bottom. I am aware that `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` with % will use the width of the container and I am fine with that.

Unfortunately when I do set the paddingTop to any value with %, it sets the paddingBottom to the same value. Basically `paddingTop: '5%', paddingBottom: '0%'` will give me equal 5% paddings on both sides.

If I set paddingBottom to any % value - it's just being added to the value that came form the top. So: `paddingTop: '5%', paddingBottom: '10%'` results in `paddingBottom` equal to 15%...

I checked the same solution in a web project and there it works as expected.

The snack presenting the problem:
https://snack.expo.io/BJ9-2t8LB

The problem is on both Android and iOS.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the value to the child container to be applied, not to the parent container.

I have modified the answer according to the conditions you want. You should send Bottom's territory to the parent's container. Because they interact with each other in their child's container, they must be independent.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
            <Text>TOP</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', }}><Text>BOTTOM</Text></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex:1,
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingRight: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    paddingBottom:"5%"
  },
  inner: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    marginTop:"10%"
  },
});
```

[image: screen]

Comment: Yeah, now you hit another variation of the problem here - the red box is not on the bottom. In this version there is a padding at the bottom equal to the marginTop height...

Comment: Should red be at the bottom of blue?

Comment: Yes, as per the web example in the snack. If you look on the code there is nothing adding any extra space there.

Comment: @Michal I've set the terms for you. Please look at the modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is strange behavior, you should bring it up as an issue to `react-native`.

In the meantime, a workaround would be applying `marginTop` and `marginBottom` to the inner `View`, instead of `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom` to the wrapper `View`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ayz:{
    marginTop:"15%",
    backgroundColor:'pink',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  },
  asd:{
    color:'white',
    fontSize:50,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).