# Why does flex start shrinking vertically, below a certain width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, jsx

I'm just testing out flex with a simple layout and I noticed that when I inspect the page and test it's responsiveness, when it gets below around 400px in width, the content start shrinking vertically, leaving a bunch of empty on the bottom space as show below. Is it normal for flex to do this below a certain width? if so, do you just use media queries to fix this or is there another method?

(the top is just header with shrunken items, which is why it looks weird)

[Here is the link as I'm not yet allowed to post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tgfb.jpg)

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#mainContent{
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(208, 255, 218);
}

.sideNav{
  background-color: rgb(159, 255, 134);
  padding: 100% 2% 100% 2%;
}
```

Home Component

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header';
import SideBar from './SideBar';

  function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Header></Header>
          <div id='mainContent'>
              <SideBar></SideBar>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Header Component

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Link} from "react-router-dom";

  function Header() {
    return (
        <div>
             <navbar className="nav-bar">
              <ul className="navItems">
                <li>
                  <h1>Groupster</h1>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </navbar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

SideBar Component

```
import React from 'react';

function SideBar() {
    return (
            <div className='sideNav'></div>
    )
}

export default SideBar
```

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: ok I will, give me a second

Comment: Try your code without the `padding-bottom: 100%`. Try a non-percentage unit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892092/how-to-use-percentage-padding-top-and-bottom-in-react-native

Comment: Without the bottom padding it doesn't reach the bottom of the screen, what would you recommend I use? also this is normal react not native

Comment: It's perfectly responsive, unless I shrink the screen to less than 400px

Comment: why do you expect that to work as you describe? if you want something to be 100% tall you can use 100vh units which is more responsive, % in paddings are really tricky

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that using 100 vh would solve this, but coders around me have told me that it is better in general to not use a set height and instead use margin/padding, hence why I'm trying to figure out a method using those.

Comment: what is shrinking? #main or .sidenav? there is no indication in your css about anything involving height